# Button default ControlTemplate, how TextElement works in trigger?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm new to wpf and try to understand how `ControlTemplate` works.

I Look into default template of `Button`, that is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:mwt="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero">

  <mwt:ButtonChrome Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding Button.IsDefaulted}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding UIElement.IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding ButtonBase.IsPressed}" Name="Chrome" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True" Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
  </mwt:ButtonChrome>

  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsKeyboardFocused">
      <Setter Property="mwt:ButtonChrome.RenderDefaulted" TargetName="Chrome">
        <Setter.Value>
          <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Trigger.Value>
        <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
      </Trigger.Value>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked">
      <Setter Property="mwt:ButtonChrome.RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome">
        <Setter.Value>
          <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Trigger.Value>
        <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
      </Trigger.Value>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled">
      <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground">
        <Setter.Value>
          <SolidColorBrush>#FFADADAD</SolidColorBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Trigger.Value>
        <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
      </Trigger.Value>
    </Trigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Mostly it looks make sense to me, `TemplateBinding` to `Control` / `mwt:ButtonChrome` / `UIElement` / `ButtonBase`, they are on the hierarchy of `ButtonBase`.

But this line confusing me, how does it work with `TextElement`, since there are no definition of it elsewhere in its template?

```
<Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled">
  <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground">
    <Setter.Value>
      <SolidColorBrush>#FFADADAD</SolidColorBrush>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Trigger.Value>
    <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
  </Trigger.Value>
</Trigger>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"TextElement.Foreground" is just a way to refer in XAML to [`ForegroundProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement.foregroundproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) dependency property defined in `TextElement` class. In c# code it can be used as `TextElement.ForegroundProperty`

It is required to change color of text which might appear in ContentPresenter (ContentPresenter itself doesn't have Foreground property)

In most cases class name can be omitted, e.g. `<Trigger Property="IsEnabled">` instead of `<Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled">`, because `ButtonBase` is `UIElement` and `IsEnabled` property is accessible inside template

Comment: is the default contentelement of a button a textelement?

Comment: @PatrickArtner, if button Content property is some string, e.g. `<Button Content="some text"/>`, there will be generated a TextBlock to display it. but it is not default, since Content can be of any type, e.g. `<Image/>`. In that case setter `TextElement.Foreground` will have no effect